# jQuery UI dialog box - multiple rows

Tags: php, jquery-ui

After a long search decided to give it a try here. I would like to implement jQuery UI dialog box for my table.
In box I want to display additional cell which has a long descripton and normally would just mess up my table layout. So after cliking the button you would get additional info.

I've got standard code:

```
$.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
$(function() {
    $( ".dialog" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: "blind",
        hide: "explode"
    });

    $( ".opener" ).click(function() {
        $( ".dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
        return false;
    });
});
```

and php:

```
   echo "<td align=center>".$okres[$i]."</td>";
   echo "<td ><button class='opener'>Desription</button><div class='dialog' title='$training[$i]'>".$opis[$i]."</div></td>";
   echo "<td align=center>".$status[$i]."</td>";
```

It does work but it opens box for all rows. Do not really know how to make it open only relevant box.

Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic ids for each row and onclick send the id of the row in question and then show the description for only that row

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
$(function() {
    $( ".opener" ).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var index=$(this).closest('tr').index();
        $($(".dialog")[index]).dialog("open");
    });
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qANMh/2/).

Comment: Hi still cannot get this to work. With this I can alert a correct id alert($(this).closest('#report tr.a').attr('id')); but the dialog displays incorrect info     $( ".opener" ).click(function() {
    
    alert($(this).closest('#report tr.a').attr('id'));
      var index=$(this).closest('#report tr.a').attr('id');
        $($(".dialog")[index]).dialog("open");     


    });